# How to get Network Infrastructure icon on Win8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, icons

Sometimes when I click on File Explorer>Network, I can see the Network Infrastructure icon. Many times there is not. How can I force Windows File Explorer to show it?

Comment: Are you talking about (un)wrapping the _Network Infrastructure_ items?

Comment: No, I am talking about icon in the Windows File Explorer. Like this at bottom:
https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/network-sharing/131587d1492941115t-windows-10-not-showing-computers-network-file-browser-cmp2virtual.png

Comment: I can confirm _Network Infrastructure_ and _Media Devices_ volatility in the  File Explorer's right pane on Win8.1 64 bit. Weird…

Comment: Yes, that's it. I sometimes need it bad, and it simply doesn't show up. And sometimes it is there. I haven't noticed any rules in the behavior.